# Intercept environment variables read by a process

Tags: operating-systems, environment-variables, debug, lsof, strace

I have a process that’s reading some environment variables to set itself up, but I’m not sure which one. The programming language is foreign to me, so let’s supposed I don’t have the source.

Is there any way I can sniff which variables it’s reading just like I would know which files this process is opening with `strace` or `lsof`.

Comment: Which programming language is it?

Comment: Java and javascript

Comment: Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

strace may be used to solve this as well for C programs and maybe more. Not possible for java programs;

```
/tmp >strace -v -s 1024 /bin/ls |& grep execve

execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], ["MANPATH=/usr/share/man", "HOME=/home/zoule", "HOSTNAME=fry01339", "SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4", "LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8", "USER=zoule",  "LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2", "_=/usr/bin/strace"]) = 0
```